# turn on assert in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

My ASP.NET asserts aren't firing.  Build configuration is debug.  what gives?

EDIT:  They are firing and silently hanging my website (exiting the thread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you probably lack this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
   <assert assertuienabled="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
```

in your web.config.

Comment: is there a way to make them more intrusive (not just log to output, like actually get in my face)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a separate server for your development ? Because an Assert will trigger a modal message box on your server which will hang your website until the message box is closed.

Comment: VS is running on the same host as the server.  But I see no box.